# TYPO3 11.5.21 error: TypoScript settings missing Unable to find TypoScript settings for module

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x, powermail

yes, it's me with a further, maybe stupid question. I'm very new in TYPO3, I just started working with it. I know some programming languages but no typoscript. Therefore I'm working with the bootstrap package first.

I made some forms with TYPO3 core and so far everything was fine but there wasn't any possibility to customize the email (to sender). Therefore I first installed "Form: Mailtexts via plugin" but afterwards the form was not working anymore and I deleted it and everything was fine again.

After some research I have found powermail for creating forms with loads of cool functions.

So, I read four different tutorials about making forms in powermail and it's not working at all.

As far as I can evaluate the problem, I would guess that the last step is the problem, placing the content on the page.

After loading the page with the powermail elements an error message is shown
`"TypoScript settings are missing. Did you include the related static templates? No form to show"`

Of course I googled this error message and found this post https://github.com/derhansen/sf_event_mgt/issues/432.

In this post they include "fluid content elements" and "Event management and registration" extension and so did I. A new icon in the backend popped up "Events". Selecting this icon a further error message is shown:
`"TypoScript settings missing Unable to find TypoScript settings for module. Please make sure, you have included the static TypoScript for the extension."`

The page with the powermail elements is empty now, i.e. no more error message but it's also not working at all.

Please, does anyone understand what's going on here? I'm devastated :-(

Many thanks in advance for your kind help!

Best,
expikx

I tried to solve the problem by internet research and experiments

Comment: Sorry, one sentence is wrong!!! The error message is still shown! sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

The plugin of powermail just informed you, that basic configuration is missing. The configuration is given via TypoScript and of course powermail brings some default configuration with it.
You now have to include them. You can do it by opening your default TypoScript template, change to the tab "Includes" and select "Main Template (powermail)". Save your template and reload your frontend.

Comment: Sorry again, it was working but on the wrong page. So I repeated every step but now there is neither an error message or the powermail form. When selecting "Templates" it is shown that there is no template on that page. I've tried all three shown possibilities but either the page cannot be loaded or it's totally empty. Any idea what went wrong here?

Comment: You normally add a typoscript template on the root page of your website. All settings are available on root and on all children pages. So, you have to add the powermail template in the root template.